# In Google Spreadsheets, how do you set a value of a cell from another cell's value after a user has clicked and activated a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am in Google Spreadsheets, I know how to create a new menu item, but how does one perform the following with google spreadsheet appscript code:

> ```
> If in cell A2, I click a menuitem "SetValue", then A2's cell value is set with value from A1.
> If in cell B2, I click a menuitem "SetValue", then B2's cell value is set with value from B1.
> If in cell C2, I click a menuitem "SetValue", then C2's cell value is set with value from C1.
> ... (and so forth and so on)
> ```

Keep in mind, the user may randomly click on any cell in row 2 before initiating the menu item function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getA1Notation()[1];
  var column = cell.getA1Notation()[0];
  if (row != 2) {
    ss.toast("not valid selection, must be in row 2");
    return;
  }
  var sourceVal = ss.getRange(column+(row - 1)).getValue();
  cell.setValue(sourceVal);
  return;
}
```

Comment: This is going to fail for columns >26...(A1 notation that uses 2 letters)

Comment: also : row is a string, you must add quotes to get an equal condition when you check row==2. I wrote a working version in another answer for convenience.

Comment: != would work fine as it uses type conversion. Quotes around the 2 would be required if using !==

Comment: right ! I must have been missing something when I tested it. sorry ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of the function shown in the other answer from @teatimer that will work for all columns. I would have written this in comments but it would have been hard to read so...

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getA1Notation().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');// keep only numeric values
  var column = cell.getA1Notation().replace(/[0-9]/g,'');//remove all numeric characters
  Logger.log('row '+row+'  column '+column);
  if (row != '2') { // row is a string, you must add quotes to get an equal condition
    ss.toast("not valid selection, must be in row 2");
    return;
  }
  var sourceVal = ss.getRange(column+(row - 1)).getValue();
  cell.setValue(sourceVal);
}
```

you can also use another form of regex to get the same result :

```
  var row = cell.getA1Notation().replace(/\d/g,'');// remove non decimal values
  var column = cell.getA1Notation().replace(/\D/g,'');//remove decimal values
```

Comment: Thanks teatimer and Serge!  @Serge - slight modification needed - flip the row and column and then it works.  Rows are numeric and Cols are non-numeric.

Comment: Oooops ! indeed ! I'll edit the code... thanks for mentioning the typo... my test was ok but I play too much with code sometimes ;-)